# Twilio Taskrouter - How to add information to custom tasks?

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I'm working with Twilio programmable video and I'd like to integrate it with TaskRouter.

Currently I can create custom tasks with a POST request to:
`https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/{WorkspaceSID}/Tasks/`

Yet regardless of what I put into the request body, the task shows up as "Anonymous Task, Reserved".

Is this an issue of formatting? I'd ideally like it to say something along the lines of "Incoming video request" with the customer name in the task-bar similar to how chat tasks look.

Here's the dummy data I tried passing in to no avail. I've tried a few different ways:

```
{
    "attributes": { 
        "type": "video", 
        "contact": "+17777777777", 
        "customer-value": "gold", 
        "task-reason": "support", 
        "callSid": "CA42ed11...",
        "name": "Joe",
        "customer_name": "Joe"
    }
    "name": "Joe",
    "customer_name": "Joe"
}
```

None of this data is passed through to the task. Any help would be appreciated.